# Opening up a seperate form in a continous form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a continuous form that my users would like to view. It is shown as below.[image]

I want to allow the user to open up a more detailed form by click on the swab locations that are specific to the asset ID. Let's say user clicks on MFG 0252.
A window with the following should pop-up. I am not sure how i can go about this. Is there a way for hyperlinks to do it? or other other methods which are better?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the OnClick event of your button:

`docmd.OpenForm "tblMainSwapLocation",acNormal,,"[Asset_ID]='"+ Me.[Asset_ID]+"'",,acDialog`

where Me.[Asset_ID] is the field name containing the Asset_ID in your form.

acDialog will open the form as PopUp

Hope this will help

Comment: I have always thought that the button will be a general function that is only tied to the first record. Like how it happens to labels, but this clears up my doubt about it